# Why can't I apply for some jobs?

Tags: support

There are some jobs on the website that aren't marked as "Applied" in the jobs list, but the "Apply" button in the job description is not availble for them; there is only the "Save" button.
I wonder why this can be happening?
For example: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/202114/front-end-software-developer-memorial-sloan-kettering

Comment: Do you have any browser add-ons that may be filtering links to `ad.doubleclick.net`? Because that's one of the jobs that have the external links instead of a link to an application on Stack Overflow. The full link of that job application is `https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/clk/410749410;217026690;y?http://careers.mskcc.org/job/8555701/front-end-software-engineer-digital-computational-pathology-new-york-ny/`, so an ad blocker might have just made the whole button disappear.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta - Ad blockers are pretty common, and some browsers have them built-in. I do expect sites to take that info consideration and not break. Furthermore, wrapping a link with a tracker is not nice. I think it's a good to report this here.

Comment: @Kobi if I decided to have ads on my site, I wouldn't then go and do extra dev to help the people blocking them...

Comment: @Kobi In this case, it isn't even an ad, its an action an user is supposed to do, an adblocker shouldn't block this, only an anti-tracker tool should block it

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Where did you read that OP blames a bug?

Comment: @Ferrybig - It's a link that goes to `ad.doubleclick.net`. Looks exactly like an ad. 

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - I advise you to read statistics on users who block ads, their volume, and their buying habits.

Comment: So, why isn't there a beacon sent when that link is clicked? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While many jobs have applications that you can fill out without leaving Stack Overflow, some jobs have applications that are hosted outside of Stack Overflow, and all of those have an external link.

In this case, the external link is `https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/clk/410749410;217026690;y?http://careers.mskcc.org/job/8555701/front-end-software-engineer-digital-computational-pathology-new-york-ny/`. Since `ad.doubleclick.net` is usually used for clicking on advertisements, an ad blocker is probably blocking the entire button from appearing.

I spent about 15 minutes searching for other job postings that use external links, but I couldn't find any, so I can't tell you how common it is for the links to go through `ad.doubleclick.net`. If this was a choice by the company who made the application by providing that link, then there's not really anything Stack Overflow Jobs can do about it. However, if SO has it set up so that all external job application links go through `ad.doubleclick.net` before getting to the final destination, then perhaps a feature request is in order to have that changed.

This could be a viable feature request since Stack Overflow has already said ["we don’t care if our users use ad blockers on Stack Overflow,"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/), in part, because "impressions served to [users] will only annoy them." Since Stack Overflow cares about not annoying their users, and disappearing job buttons could be considered pretty annoying when using a pretty standard (in many cases considered necessary)<sup>1</sup> tool like ad-block, they would probably be willing to listen to a feature request regarding changing how the off-site job application buttons are served.

Of course, not caring about ad blockers is not equivalent to saying they're willing to spend the dev time to make every little part of the site work around them (If I recall correctly, there was a time that Ad Block Plus was removing all of the social media buttons, and the response was something like "If you want to use those buttons, just turn off ad block"). If this is the fault of the company providing a link that is blocked, then I can't see Stack Overflow taking any action, but if this is done by Stack Overflow, then they might be willing to make a change to how the button is rendered.

<sup>1</sup><sub>There are many reasons already on the web about why using adblockers can help with security, such as when [an ad is hacked to include malware or redirect your page](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/601057/are-ad-blockers-needed-to-stay-safe-online/), so some companies go to great lengths to make sure their website is fully functional below an ad blocker since they expect so many users to use them.</sub>

Comment: "_Stack Overflow cares about not annoying their users_"^[citation needed]

Comment: @AndradDeak I already gave a citation and a direct quote, what more do you need?

Comment: @AndrasDeak The full quote is "The truth is: we don’t care if our users use ad blockers on Stack Overflow. More accurately: we hope that they won’t, but we understand that some people just don’t like ads. Our belief is that if someone doesn’t like them, and they won’t click on them, any impressions served to them will only annoy them." If they specify that, then drawing the conclusion "Stack Overflow cares about not annoying their users" is pretty direct.